# Is that the right way to write a script that search for some words into the clipboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner with python and I was trying to write a program that search for some words (as arguments) into the clipboard.

I wrote some code and it seems to work. But I want to know how some experienced programers could write that kind of program, and if I did some mistakes.

```
#! python3
# searcher.py - Searches in the clipboard the occurence of some words specified as arguments.
# Usage: py.exe searcher.py <word1> <word2>...

import re, sys, pyperclip


#Make sure there is at least one argument.
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print('You have to enter a word as an argument')

#Find the occurences in clipboard text.
text = pyperclip.paste()
matches = []
for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    word = sys.argv[i]         
    text_regex = re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(word), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    for occurences in text_regex.findall(text):
        matches.append(occurences)

# Copy results to the clipboard.
if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No occurences found')
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: you can change `text_regex = re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(word), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    for occurences in text_regex.findall(text):
        matches.append(occurences)` to `matches.append(re.findall(r'\b({0})\b'.format(word),text))`

Comment: `if len(sys.argv) == 1: ...else: sys.exit(0)`